# Tiff to Pdf converter with python for over 2gb tif files

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a .tif to pdf converter with python using PIL sn reportlab.pdfgen but getting tis error

> Image size (1600769640 pixels) exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.

I tried increasing max pixels manually but no luck for me. Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


def tif_to_pdf(input_tif_path, output_pdf_path, max_pixels=5419233468):
    try:

        img = Image.open(input_tif_path)


        if img.size[0] * img.size[1] > max_pixels:
            raise ValueError(f"Resim boyutu ({img.size[0]}x{img.size[1]}) izin verilen sınırı ({max_pixels} piksel) aşıyor.")


        pdf = canvas.Canvas(output_pdf_path)

 
        for page_num in range(img.n_frames):
            img.seek(page_num)
            pdf.drawInlineImage(img, 0, 0)

            if page_num < img.n_frames - 1:
                pdf.showPage()


        pdf.save()

        print(f"PDF dosyası başarıyla oluşturuldu: {output_pdf_path}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Hata oluştu: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:

        input_tif_path = input("Lütfen TIF dosyasının yolunu girin: ")


        output_pdf_path = input("Lütfen oluşturulacak PDF dosyasının yolunu girin: ")


        print(f"Girilen TIF dosyası yolu: {input_tif_path}")
        print(f"Girilen PDF dosyası yolu: {output_pdf_path}")


        tif_to_pdf(input_tif_path, output_pdf_path)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Hata oluştu: {e}")
```

sorry for the messed up code blocks but I couldn't figure out how to properly write them for this question.

Comment: What's the point of this?  An 8.5 x 11 sheet at 300 dpi is only 8 megapixels.  Your images are 200 times larger than that.  If you want to build a PDF, why not reduce the resolution?

Comment: My main goal just be able to display .tiff files that big somehow.  i tried with asp.net libraries, js libraries and other things but none of them work. So i decided to try python for just displaying but no luck. looks like converting is the way to go for me.

Comment: Try adding this as your second line `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None` if you really choose to ignore Tim's advice.

Comment: Putting them in a PDF is not a good way to "display" them.  Most image applications can display TIFF files, but you're talking about 40,000 x 40,000 pixels here.  That's the size of 400 HD monitors.  How do you think people are going to view these?  Perhaps you should reduce the resolution for your PDF, and have a link to the full-size image online.